# Unity 3D Particle System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity 3D and want to enable a Particle System on my Enemy GameObject when it gets destroyed  with the Destroy() function and I don't know if there is a good way to do that. My idea is to create a new invisible GameObject and let the particles play on the invisible one. Could somebody help me and maybe also give me step-by-step instructions? Thanks if somebody considers to help.

I also didn't find anything that says something like On Destroy or something. Help?

Comment: This question would be better asked at [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), but to answer you could spawn the particles at the enemies position with a simple DestroyAfterTime scipt where you set `Destroy(gameObject, delay)` in the `Awake()` method where `delay` is a `float` that represents how long you want to wait before destroying the `GameObject`

Answer (score 0):

You can try instantiating a particle system(Prefab) on that OnDestroy function.